# Javascript object nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, module

I was working here yesterday, converting some old spaghetti jquery code to a modular pattern and then I started to think about this:

How would I do some thing like this?
Is that possible?

```js
var obj = {
    insideObj1: {
        moreInsideObj1: {
            evenMoreInsideObj1: {
             //How could I reference the "moreInsideObj1" from here
            },
            evenMoreInsideObj2: {
             //How could I reference the "insideObj1" from here
            },
            evenMoreInsideObj2: {
             //How could I reference the "obj" from here
            }

        },
        moreInsideObj2: {
         //How could I do the same thing here
        },
    },
    insideObj2: {
     //Here I can use "this.insideObj1" right;
    }
};
```

**I'm new to the JS and JQuery world.

What about something like this:

```js
var obj = (function(){
    insideObj1: {
        moreInsideObj1: {
            evenMoreInsideObj1: {
             //How could I reference the "moreInsideObj1" from here
            },
            evenMoreInsideObj2: {
             //How could I reference the "insideObj1" from here
            },
            evenMoreInsideObj2: {
             //How could I reference the "obj" from here
            }

        },
        moreInsideObj2: {
         //How could I do the same thing here
        },
    },
    insideObj2: {
     //Here I can use "this.insideObj1" right;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily:

```js
var a = obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj1.evenMoreInsideObj1;
var b = obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj1.evenMoreInsideObj2;
var c = obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj1.evenMoreInsideObj2;
var d = obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj2;
```

Simply add another dot to go one deeper.

Comment: yeah, that's ok, but would it be possible to do something like this.insideObj1.moreInsideObj1.evenMoreInsideObj1, even from the deepest object ?

Comment: the 'this' keyword will always refer to the first obj or it will refer to the first parent?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'd like to set a deeper object equal to a shallower object?
Eg. 
`obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj1.evenMoreInsideObj1 = obj.insideObj1.moreInsideObj2;`

Comment: yep, something like that. **The question is something that made me curious, i'm not really doing it.